# 403 Forbidden error when accessing Google Drive API downloadURL

Tags: google-drive-api

I've been doing a lot of development locally with the Google Drive API, but suddenly I'm no longer able to access files using the downloadUrl link.

I'm wondering if I've been blocked or anything, although I can't see how as I should be well under the API limit. The 403 isn't the friendly Google one, but a standard:

HTTP Error 403 (Forbidden): The server refused to fulfill the request

Any ideas? Thanks!

Comment: Have you tried using another IP address? (or using a proxy)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Check the [error messages on the 403 responses](https://developers.google.com/drive/handle-errors), it will give you some information. You may have to perform [exponential backoff](https://developers.google.com/drive/handle-errors#implementing_exponential_backoff).

Comment: That was it thanks! Looks like I'll have to rethink my approach.

Answer (score 1):

you are accessing google drive file using download url bt download url is expired after some time so that you catch error and generate new request for that file